# How to accept alert in the popup window using selenium?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

When the pop-up window opens, the alert is directly throwing. When I check the page source, it comes empty but when I click OK or hit enter. The page source is coming. I tried to switch alert and accept, selenium did not see the alert. I tried to send the Enter key to any element of the pop-up window, it still didn't work. I am not forgetting to switch the pop-up window. How can I switch that alert?

[image: Pop-up Window]

Comment: I am checking the source from the code. I can't right-click while alert presenting

Answer (score 0):

```
driver.switchTo().alert().accept();
```

Comment: I think you didn't read it.  "I tried to switch alert and accept, selenium did not see the alert."

Comment: This single line of code does not answer the question.  Please explain how this line of code answers the author's question.